# Reset Redux state to undefined or initial state except one state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a redux store where I have defined all the application using combineReducers. What I want to achieve is this, I want to reset all of the state to undefined except one state when the user logout.
example below works fine but what if I have more than 8 states, I will end up having long code. Is there way where I can simplify this, perhaps to loop through the appReducers?:

```
const appReducer = combineReducers({
        num1,
        num2,
        num3,
        num4,
        ...createForms({})
    });
const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
if (action.type === 'LOGOUT') {
    delete state.num1;
    delete state.num2;
    delete state.num3;
}

return appReducer(state, action) // this will always return num4 state.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you modify a state in redux, it will return new state object,
So if you want to clear out all the state then simply

```
if (action.type === 'RESET') {
  return undefined
}
```

If you want to persist only state with key 'persist'

you can simply return

```
if (action.type === 'LOGOUT') {
  return { num4: state.num4 }
}
```

Comment: I do not want to persist the state for now, I just wanna clear all the states except num4 state every time the use logout.

Comment: please check my updated answer, you just need to return object with `num4` property init

Comment: thanks! It does return only one state now when the user logout.